# Android 14 context registered broadcast receivers not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-14

I'm experimenting with my app on an Android 14 device, where I'm sending a local broadcast and then subscribing to it within the app. However, when I utilize the `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` option, the broadcast is not being received at all.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
private var \_binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val dashboardViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
    
        _binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
    
        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            Intent("com.nama.action").also { intent ->
                intent.putExtra("nama", dashboardViewModel.text.value)
                requireContext().sendBroadcast(intent)
            }
        }
    
        val textView: TextView = binding.textDashboard
        dashboardViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
    
    
        val br: BroadcastReceiver = MyBroadcastReceiver()
        val filter = IntentFilter("com.nama.action")
        ContextCompat.registerReceiver(requireContext().applicationContext, br, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
    
    
        return root
    }
    
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

When I run with the `RECEIVER_EXPORTED` I am able to receive the broadcast. According to the Google docs, we do not need to export the local notifications that are used in the same app?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you running on an Android 14 device and also upgraded your build.gradle for Android 14?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes. By build.gradle set to target & compile sdk version to 34. Running on an Android 14(beta) device.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For intents with custom action you need to specify package name when sending broadcast.

```
intent.setPackage(context.packageName)
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/293487554

Comment: Logical, and worked for me too

Comment: Excellent information, I do not understand why google do not update docs properly. I was struggling with same issue and finally landed here.

Comment: I spent hours to figured out, you saved my day 